# toilet is continually clogged

Tags: plumbing-fixture

Appreciate if someone can tell by not providing good sealing of the toilet bowl "s" trap pipe going into the floor affects the flushing strength / clogging or just leads to escape of gases

Answer (score 2):

If the wax seal is misaligned enough it could potentially lead to clogging, though I would also expect water on the floor if that is the case.

If the toilet was just seated poorly, then your risks are escape of gas and escape of sewage.

Frequent clogs are usually caused by an obstruction, either in the toilet itself or downstream.  Venting problems usually manifest as gurgling or slow draining versus a complete clog.

Comment: Thanks, Steven. Is it possible that the problem is the design of the pan / cistern. the cistern is 4.5/3 Liters, as there is no gurgling, water leak or gas escape, the system is flushing normal when the load is not heavy, the problem is when it is a heavy load.

Comment: Some toilets are better than others.